# overlaying a plot without axis title in R (without ggplot2)

Tags: r

I couldn't find the answer to my question anywhere on forum. I have two plots at the moment, one of which is the zoomed in of another plot. For instance, I have the following:

```
    attach(mtcars)
plot(wt, mpg, main="Scatterplot Example", 
     xlab="Car Weight ", ylab="Miles Per Gallon ", pch=19)

plot(wt, mpg, main="Scatterplot Example", 
     xlab="Car Weight ", ylab="Miles Per Gallon ", pch=19, xlim=c(0, 3) )
```

I have trying to overlay the 2nd plot (with the xlim onto the right upper corner of the plot) depicted by this picture.

[image]

At first I tried assigning the plot into a character and use the following code below, however that didn't work.

```
vp <- viewport(x=0.78,y=0.75,width=0.35, height=0.338)

full <- function() {
  print(g1)
  theme_set(theme_bw(base_size = 8))
  print(subplot2, vp = vp)
}

full()
```

For clarifications, g1 is the big plot while subplot2 is the plot i'd like to overlay.

Any help would be much appreciated. Is there a way to make the overlay happen?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I cannot seem to overlay the two plots. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `par(fig=c(0.5,1,0.5,1), new=TRUE)` like so. The numbers inside the `fig` option are x0,x1,y0,y1 and represent percentage of the plot. In this case, the figure starts (x0) at 50% of the x-axis and ends (x1) at 100% of the original axis.

```
plot(wt, mpg, main="Scatterplot Example", 
     xlab="Car Weight ", ylab="Miles Per Gallon ", pch=19)
par(fig=c(0.5,1,0.5,1), new=TRUE)
plot(wt, mpg, main="", 
     xlab="Car Weight ", ylab="Miles Per Gallon ", pch=19, xlim=c(0, 3) )
```

[image]