# Overlay plot on top of another

Tags: r, patchwork

This question leads off from this one:

[force plot onto next frame without erasing the previous plot (using packages plotrix, bpDir, circular)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77293534/force-plot-onto-next-frame-without-erasing-the-previous-plot-using-packages-plo/77294472#77294472)

I have the following plot using `patchwork` in `R`:

```r
library(circular)
data(fisherB12c)
library(bpDir)
library(patchwork)

p <- wrap_elements(full = ~CircularBoxplot(fisherB12c, template="geographics")) 
p2 <- wrap_elements(full = ~CircularBoxplot(fisherB12c, template="geographics", shrink = 2)) 
p + p2
```

gives me the plot side-by-side.

However, I am wondering if there is a way to overlay the second plot on top of the first plot. I don't know if `patchwork` can do this.

Sorry, if I am not clear: I am looking for one plot, with the distribution (on the right, same in this case) diplayed on the same figure, but at a different radius (per `shrink`) as the first one.

Comment: It might be easier to do a single plot with combined data; for instance, `ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl, disp, group=cyl)) + geom_boxplot() + coord_polar(theta = "y") + scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0,10))` nests polar-oriented boxplots. (Obviously the "theta" variable here needs better control, _easily done_. I'm just showing that it can be done.).

Comment: (I might be able to demonstrate using your data if you can share it; if so, [edit] your question and add the output from `dput(fisherB12c)`; if it's large-ish data, then either use a public dataset or generate something programmatically, even random data.)

Comment: My apologies, the data are in `circular` -- I did not realize I omitted that. Edited.

Comment: @r2evans, just wanted to clarify that this is a circular boxplot, not a boxplot of (linear) data done in polar coordinates.

Comment: I'm not certain I understand the distinction, so I'm holding off to learn what others recommend. is the distinction that this circ-boxplot acknowledge cyclic data?

Comment: @r2evans, that is indeed correct. The data are directional. It would be good to have a ggplot2 solution though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer from [overlaying a plot without axis title in R (without ggplot2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44322041/overlaying-a-plot-without-axis-title-in-r-without-ggplot2?rq=2) without using `patchwork`.

```
library(circular)
data(fisherB12c)
library(bpDir)
CircularBoxplot(fisherB12c, template="geographics", shrink = 1.5) 
par(new = T)
CircularBoxplot(fisherB12c, template="geographics", shrink = 2)
```

This gives me:

[image]

Perhaps there is a better answer than this kludge. Of course, a better way to do this would be to modify the rather inflexible `CircularBoxplot` function. But for a quick display, this is an option.